# Racket macro for expanding code

Tags: macros, pattern-matching, racket, define-syntax

I want to be able to write:

```
(nota E2 82)
```

instead of:

```
(define E2
  (network ()
           [sunet <= sine-wave 82]
           [out = (+ sunet)]))
```

I know I can do this using macros and tried to write this:

```
(define-syntax (nota stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(nota x) #'(network ()
                         [sunet <= sine-wave x]
                         [out = (+ sunet)])]))
```

But I get this error:

```
nota: bad syntax in: (nota E2 82)
```

Comment: Did you forget the `define`?

Comment: The reason you’ve gotten the “bad syntax” error is because `(nota x)` indicates your macro only takes a single “argument”, but you’ve given it two. As @stchang mentions, it looks like you want to add an extra argument and include the `define` in your expansion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be

```
(define-syntax-rule (nota x y)
  (define x
    (network ()
             [sunet <= sine-wave y]
             [out = (+ sunet)])))
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, that's just awful. You really shouldn't need to write this macro; there should be a form that supplies fixed inputs to a network.

In fact, there is. But... it's not documented, and it's not well named. It's currently called `fixed-inputs`, but I'm going to rename it as `network-const`, and document it.

Thanks for prompting me on this!

John

Comment: For future proofing this answer, can you link to the docs when you do? (And when the next version of Racket with it is released.)